# Django 3 models.Q - app_lable gets displayed inside html

Tags: python, django, model

since I upgraded to Django 3.x I have a strage behaviour.
Imaging the following field at your models.py

```
content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=filter_choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

which refers to:

```
filter_choice = models.Q(app_label='App', model='model_x') | models.Q(app_label='App', model='model_y')
```

If I now display the content_type field on my html templates it look like this: "App| Model Y" which looks quite stupid, same goes for Django admin. Is this a Bug? I'm asking because on Django 2.2.7 (Latest version of 2.x) I dont had this behaviour and only model_x and model_y have been displayed as expected.
Would be awesome if only model_x and model_y getting displayd without there app lables. Is there any solution for this, maybe a new option that comes with django 3.x?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: No, this is just how the `__str__` of a `content_type` is defined. But normally you never render `ContentType` objects in your templates, since this are the tecnical details of your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I now display the content_type field on my html templates it look like this: `"App| Model Y"` which looks quite stupid.

This is how the `__str__` of a `ContentType` is implemented. Indeed, if we take a look at the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py#L144-L145), we see:

> ```
> class ContentType(models.Model):
>
>     # …
>
>     def __str__(self):
>         return self.app_labeled_name
>
>     # …
>
>     @property
>     def app_labeled_name(self):
>         model = self.model_class()
>         if not model:
>             return self.model
>         return '%s | %s' % (model._meta.app_label, model._meta.verbose_name)
> ```

If you want to render the model name however, you can for example use:

```
{{ object.content_type.model_class._meta.verbose_name }}
```

It makes sense to include the app label, since the same model name can be used in different apps, hence it is possible that your project has two `Model Y`s, in two different apps.

Furthermore it is not very common to render a `ContentType` in the template. Normally this is part of the technical details of your project, that you likely do not want to expose. If you need to show the type of the object in a `GenericForeignKey`, you can simply follow the `GenericForeignKey`, and render the `._meta.verbose_name` of that object.

Comment: just object.content_type.name works also fine :)
Thanks again for your explanation